# Shoud i use meta attributes or json-ld

Tags: metadata, meta-tags, json-ld

As I'm new to the SEO, can someome guide me regarding where to use Meta Title , description and keyword or is there a way to do it with json-ld only. I mean to say that can I use only json-ld to specify all the meta attributes required by a search engine or should i use both, as Meta tags to define the Page meta and Json-ld for structured data. Also, please throw some light on the use of "meta property= og:", means what is the use of "og:" here.
Can I rely only on Json-Ld ( Without using any meta data)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. SEO is on-topic on [webmasters.se] (but your question would likely be too broad).

Comment: ok thanks, I am posting my question on webmasters